# Image in H2 (unique per h2)

Tags: html, css, seo

I created a custom H2 CSS markup with gives the H2 a full-with blue background and white letters inside.

Now I want to add a custom small icon in some of these h2's.

for example I have an h2 called Features, now I want to add a small gear icon in front of it.

What is the best way to proceed in terms of:
- SEO: Is it a problem to have an image inside my h2
- coding: I just added it as a  inside the H2 tags, but now the image is not aligned in the center (vertically).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This can be solved by having an img-element inside the h2-element.

But remember, since this is a decorative image, you need to have an empty alt-attribute. More information: [Accessibility Tip: Empty alt Attributes](https://davidwalsh.name/accessibility-tip-empty-alt-attributes)

```
<h2>
  <img src="gear.svg" alt=""> 
  Features
</h2>
```

Tip: Use flexbox to vertical align the icon and text

```
h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```